# Get list of users who have logged into Octopus in the last 6 months

Tags: powershell, authentication, octopus-deploy

I was wondering if there is a way to find out what users have logged into Octopus Deploy in the last 3 months. I am able get a list of users in Octopus by using an REST API call: 
Invoke-RestMethod "$OctopusUrl/api/users?take=500" -Headers $header.
I cant see an API call to get user login activity. Just want to ask if anyone knows a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can potentially see two ways of doing this

1) Use the `api/events` endpoint. This will allow you to provide a range of dates using the `from` and `to` parameters. You would then have to enumerate all records and pull out the distinct users you come across - you probably want to narrow this by ensuring the account authenticated with a cookie `"IdentityEstablishedWith": "Session cookie"`

2) Use the results from the `api/users` to call the `api/events` endpoint, with the date range and the specific user e.g. `?users=Users-1`. Here, you only need to check if you get more than 1 result with the `"IdentityEstablishedWith": "Session cookie"` field set correctly

Hope this helps